# JTree set transparency of Icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, rendering, jtree

I want to give a visual indication that a node has been transferred to clipboard with a "Cut" action.  One intuitive look used by at least one proprietary OS is to make this the same image, but slightly transparent.

I'd quite like to know whether it is in fact possible somehow to use the icons used by the Windoze OS (W7)... but I'd be more intrigued if it were possible to interfere in some way (in the renderer) with the Icon, by somehow messing with the Graphics object used by Icon.paintIcon() ... just for a given node, obviously.  I'm not clear where an Icon goes hunting for the Graphics object it uses when it is painted ... any enlightenment would be most welcome.

***later***

Many thanks to MadProgrammer.  Spotted this possibility as a way of extracting obfuscated visuals with a view to their manipulation: https://home.java.net/node/674913 ... it works.  Putting code here in case of broken link...

```
public class IconTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Icon leafIcon = UIManager.getIcon("Tree.leafIcon"); 
        // ... ("Tree.closedIcon") ("Tree.openIcon")

        BufferedImage img1 = new BufferedImage(leafIcon.getIconWidth(),
                leafIcon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics g = img1.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(((ImageIcon) leafIcon).getImage(), 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img1, "PNG", new File("leafIcon.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error writing to file leafIcon" + ", e = " + e);
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

}
```

Then use MadProgrammer's technique to alter the image in any way one likes: change transparency, colour, etc.  Great stuff.

Comment: You can use [`FileSystemView#getSystemIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemIcon(java.io.File)) to get OS's icon for a specified file.  To create a "alpha" based icon, create a `BufferedImage` of the same size as the `Icon`, apply a `AlphaComposite` to the `BufferedImage`'s `Graphics` context, paint the `Icon` to the `BufferedImage`'s `Graphics` context the wrap the `BufferedImage` in a `ImageIcon`, which will allow you to use it as a `Icon`

Comment: Useful, thanks very much.  A simple bit of experimenting showed me that subclassing IconUIResource and overriding paintIcon does not enable you to interfere with the image of the actual icon itself.  I wonder if you have any idea where the icon images used by particular Java L&Fs are actually stored?  Can we access them and make a BufferedImage of them, I wonder?

Comment: Generally speaking no.  Icons in the L&F are stored in a number of different ways depending on what they are used for. For example, you can access some using `UIManager.getIcon`, but others, like the file icons, need to be obtained through some system call.  Generally speaking it's not safe to cast a `Icon` to a `BufferedImage`, instead, you need to paint the icon to a `BufferedImage` manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd quite like to know whether it is in fact possible somehow to use the icons used by the Windoze OS (W7)

[`FileSystemView#getSystemIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#getSystemIcon(java.io.File)) will give you the OS's icon representation of a given `File`, for example...

```
Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File("ThatImportantDoc.docx"));
```

> I want to give a visual indication that a node has been transferred to clipboard with a "Cut" action. One intuitive look used by at least one proprietary OS is to make this the same image, but slightly transparent.

You need to paint the previous `Icon` to `BufferedImage`, which has had a `AlphaComposite` applied to it, for example

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
icon.paintIcon(null, g2d, 0, 0);
g2d.dispose();
```

You then need to wrap the resulting `BufferedImage` in a `ImageIcon`, which allows you to pass the image as a `Icon` to the rest of the API.

[image: Faded Icon]

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new JLabel(icon));
panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Icon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

To get this to finally work, you will need to provide a `TreeCellRenderer` capable of supporting your functionality.  Have a look at [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Just one tweak enabling me to do what I mainly wanted to do: get the UI images "from the source code".

```
public class IconTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // OS folder icon
//              Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File("."));
        // proprietary word processor
//              Icon icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(new File("Doc1.docx"));
        // taken from PNG file
//              Icon icon = new ImageIcon( "openIcon.png" );
        // taken directly from the Java images held somewhere (?) in the code
        Icon icon = UIManager.getIcon("Tree.leafIcon"); 
//              Icon icon  = UIManager.getIcon("Tree.openIcon"); 
        // ... ("Tree.closedIcon") ("Tree.openIcon")

        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage( icon.getIconWidth(),
                icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive( 0.5f));
        icon.paintIcon(null, g2d, 0, 0);
        g2d.dispose();              

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel(icon));
        panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel, "Icon", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);              

    }
}
```